# Link encryption?

Tags: url, hyperlink, server-side

I have been stuck on a problem for a few hours. Nothing online has helped and I'm losing the will to live right now.

The site loads up a question with no hints and asks you to find a secret code.

Here's the brief explanation of it:

'Well done on making it to the secret bonus challenge! Our agents have been struggling to deal with a hacker obsessed with clocks and timing. He set up an elaborate collection of pages with content that changes based on a timer. We've replicated it below, can you figure out how to get the secret code?'

There are many links inside this challenge and when they are clicked it opens to a new website and has pseudo strings in there, I don't see much pattern. Links below:

https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D

https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt2?verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D

https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt3?
verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D

https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt4?
verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D

https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt5?verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D

(If it doesn't allow you to go on) then what it has is just a  tag and no element with what it seems a three character code which always ends in 'a' for example 'Aja' and makes a new one every 10 seconds (which is not re-generated client side.)

Anyone have any suggestions to whether or not the link is a hint of encryption or not? I've decrypted it once and it came up with: 
'https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt5?verify=BY/8lhw tbBgvOMDiHeB5A==' which isn't much help.

Anyways, anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this a programming problem, or are you asking us for help with a game you're playing?

Comment: That pair of `==` at the end is a telltale marker for base-64 encoded data.  Maybe do what you did there for all the URLs, concatenate the parts after "BY/" and then base-64 decode.

Comment: I'll try that @lockcmpxchg8b

Comment: It's a website with different challenges and you have to find out the secret code using the tools given

Comment: Forgot to mention. There's another link which is a verification. https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/get-flag?verify=BY%2F8lhw%2BtbBgvOMDiHeB5A%3D%3D&string=<clock pts>

Comment: I've also tried to web scrape but the problem with that is I cannot select the strings inside the links because they're just <body> elements.

Comment: So you are asking to have a puzzle solved for you? That is ridiculous.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b The OP probably does not understand that `%2F`, `%2B` and `%3D` are encodings for `/`,`+` and `=`. Nor Base64.

Comment: @zaph, maybe we should refer him to the URL Encoding Reference at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

Its not impossible. I have the answer here:

import requests

page1 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt1?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D"

page1_content = requests.get(page1)

page1txt = page1_content.text

page2 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt2?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D"

page2_content = requests.get(page2)

page2txt = page2_content.text

page3 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt3?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D"

page3_content = requests.get(page3)

page3txt = page3_content.text

page4 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt4?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D"

page4_content = requests.get(page4)

page4txt = page4_content.text

page5 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/clock-pt5?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D"

page5_content = requests.get(page5)

page5txt = page5_content.text

code = (page1txt + page2txt + page3txt + page4txt + page5txt)

page6 = "https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/challenge-files/get-flag?verify=wMHfxKSix2qSPJtLe6U98w%3D%3D&string="+code

page6txt = requests.get(page6)

print (page6txt.text)

Replace all of the links with the links you are given